# What should I do if I want to prevent cheating by substituting values on front-end?

Tags: javascript, client-server

I create a game and I save the scores in database.
As you know we can change variables in inspect element and change `ner = score` to `ner = 50000`, then play the game and it will post 50000 score.
I don't want that change to make an effect.
Any solution?

```
// this is my post code:

ner = score, ter = $("#namesee").val(), $.post("http://localhost/sargarmi/scores.php", { morin: ter, eldo: ner }, function(e) { JSON.parse(e) })
```

Comment: Obfuscate your code, but you cannot prevent this from happening.

Comment: No, that's impossible. Physical access is always on top of the privilege order, and the user will always be able to do whatever he or she wants with code executed on their system. You can add security by obscurity, but it will never prevent anyone who really tries.

Comment: No, there's no client-side solution, a visitor can access any script and variable on your page, and they can send what ever information they want.

Comment: This is a classic issue which boils down to: You can't trust the client. Any data sent up could be modified. The only way to make this somewhat safe, is to have the server do the scoring (But obviously the game itself could still be "cheated")

Answer (score 0):

The comments above are totally true: you cannot rely on the client. Attacker can easily track what data you send and simply substitute values and make another request.

In order to prevent such cheating you need to perform score calculations on server side. I am not aware of what kind of a game you are implementing, but let's take a simple quiz game as an example. In that case your API should return questions and user should send back the answers. Then answers are checked on the server, score is calculated and saved into the database.